# AOSP on Nexus 5X: How to get root

Tags: android, android-source

I am working on building AOSP for nexus 5X. code builds and installs and runs,

but when trying to access adb shell, I couldn't get to su.

I checked and /system/xbin/su is now in su_exec tag, so I modified file_contexts to put su in system tag

```
shell@bullhead:/ $ which su
/system/xbin/su
shell@bullhead:/ $ ls -Z /system/xbin/su
-rwsr-x--- root     shell             u:object_r:system_file:s0 su
```

But still:

```
shell@bullhead:/ $ su
su: setgid failed: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried disabling selinux but:

```
shell@bullhead:/ $ setenforce 0                                                
setenforce: Couldn't set enforcing status to '0': Permission denied
```

I am out of ideas now. Please help.

Comment: What branch/version of AOSP are you working on?

Comment: MMB29Q/6.0.1_r11 straight from repo, no local mods, except as stated above

Comment: I use `lunch aosp_bullhead-userdebug` for 5X

Comment: I'd like to add, this wasn't a problem with nexus 7/2013 (flo) with LMY48M (5.1.1_r14). Building AOSP for that device, with `aosp_flo-userdebug`, then issuing su on ADB shell landed you on root prompt without issues

Comment: **This is not supposed to work**.  If you need to poke around your prototype system as root, create an engineering build where you will automatically be root under adb, or create a userdebug build and run `adb root` on the host.  Don't try to su.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Please add this as answer so I can accept it. FYI, my build was userdebug, but I couldn't get root on that. eng builds always open adb shell as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adb root with userdebug build doesn't work for me.

to get root, I had to make an eng bui. on this build, adb always lands in root shell.

Thanks @Chris for answer.